# Why does my code for a floating point accumulator throw an exception in C with inline assembly made on visual studio?

Tags: x86, floating-point, inline-assembly

So, as a bit of context, I have to make a program that calculates the regression line for a given number of points as a school project using inline assembly.

I don't know where, but some lines throw exceptions. In order to try and solve them, I first tried to make an isolated floating point accumulator using the FLD and FSTP instructions, here shown:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define NUM_OF_POINTS 1000000

int main(void) {
  
   
    float* vector = (float*)malloc(NUM_OF_POINTS * sizeof(float));
    
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_POINTS; i++)
        vector[i] = 10000;

    //Acts as the acumulator
    float sum = 0;
    //i is used as the loop counter, k as the limit
    int i = 0, k = NUM_OF_POINTS*4;
    
    _asm 
    {
    looop:;

    ;We bring the value from k to EAX to do the comparasion
        mov EAX, k;
    ;Conditional flags
        cmp i, EAX;
    ;If both values are equal que go to the end: label
        je end;

    ;We put the first element of vector on the stack
        mov ESI, vector;
        add ESI, i;
        FLD [ESI];
    ;We put the sum in the stack
        FLD sum;
    ;We add the sum and the element of the vector
        FADD;
    ;We put the calculated value in the sum
        FSTP sum;
    ;We remove the element of the vector from the stack
        add ESP, 4;
    ;We increment the loop counter by 4
        add i, 4;
    ;The loop begins once again
        jmp looop;

    end:;
    }


    printf("here you go: %f", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I thought it would print me the value without issue, but instead, Visual Studio tells me that the printf causes an exception (0xC0000005) due to an access infraction when trying to write in an invalid direction. Now, I assume the exception is not caused by the printf on itself, rather a mistake I made when using the stack or maybe because the sum variable suffers overflow? Maybe because I should use pop instead of adding 4 to the ESP register? Some advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I don't think `add ESP, 4;` is right here. You're working on the FP stack, not the regular one that `esp` addresses.

Comment: The simplest way to see what your loop should be like is  to set code generation to x87 and compile the C code then look at it in the debugger You have missed a trick in the use of the x87 stack for the accumulator since temporary values held on the x87 stack are more precise than ordinary float or double precision reals. Saving it to sum and reloading inside the loop wastes memory bandwidth and slows it down. First delete "add ESP,4" and then try following it in the debugger to see what else goes wrong. Initialising your vector as vector[i] = i will help make things clearer too.

Comment: To pop the FP stack, use `fstp st0`.  Or better, use `faddp` instead of `fadd` so it's already balanced.  Or even better, don't store/reload `sum` inside the loop, keep it in `st0` and use `fadd [esi]` / `add esi, 4` to iterate through the array.   Use a debugger to watch registers.  You don't need to store/reload `i` or `k` either, just keep an end-pointer in another register that you computed ahead of the first iteration.  Like `lea edx, [esi + NUM_OF_POINTS*4]` and `fldz` so your loop can be `looop:` `fadd [esi]` / `add esi, 4` / `cmp esi, edx` / `jb looop`.  Then after the loop, `fstp sum`

Comment: @PeterCordes, thanks. I figured out a way in order to avoid reloading/saving the value in the variable over and over and now it works. I guess pushing and pulling the information might have cause memory loss or modified the value so much that it was causing errors.

Comment: No, you were just overflowing the FP stack since you had more pushes than pops, resulting in NaN.  See rule #1 in http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/fpuchap1.htm